# Attribute Error: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'root'

Tags: python, tkinter

I don’t understand why this error appears, I have two source codes in one, everything works fine, in the second this error comes out. Looked at [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62219865/attributeerror-tkinter-tkapp-object-has-no-attribute-root)

but it did not give a result

```
try:
from Tkinter import *  # for Python2
```

except ImportError:
from tkinter import *  # for Python3

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master = master
    self.initialize_user_interface()

def initialize_user_interface(self):
    self.master.root.title("Работа с планом")
    self.master.root.geometry('400x300+200+200')

    self.lbl_name = Label(root, text='Название проекта:', font=("Arial Bold", 14))
    self.lbl_name.grid(column=0, row=1)
    self.txt_name = Entry(root, width=50, font=("Arial Bold", 14))
    self.txt_name.grid(column=1, row=1)

    self.lbl_lic = Label(root, text='Жидкость для работы:')
    self.lbl_lic.grid(column=0, row=2)
    self.txt_lic = Entry(root, width=50, font=("Arial Bold", 14))
    self.txt_lic.grid(column=1, row=2)

    self.lbl_tank = Label(root, text='Имя танкера для работы:')
    self.lbl_tank.grid(column=0, row=3)
    self.txt_tank = Entry(root, width=50, font=("Arial Bold", 14))
    self.txt_tank.grid(column=1, row=3)

    self.lbl_desk = Label(root, text='Описание действий сотрудника:')
    self.lbl_desk.grid(column=0, row=4)
    self.txt_desk = Entry(root, width=50, font=("Arial Bold", 14))
    self.txt_desk.grid(column=1, row=4)

    self.lbl_agr = Label(root, text='Согласование работ с нормоконтролером:')
    self.lbl_agr.grid(column=0, row=5)
    self.txt_agr = Entry(root, width=50, font=("Arial Bold", 14))
    self.txt_agr.grid(column=1, row=5)
    self.txt_name.focus()

    self.but_b = Button(root, text="Назад", font=("Arial Bold", 14))
    self.but_b.grid(column=0, row=6)
    self.but_go = Button(root, text="Вперед", font=("Arial Bold", 14), command=self.safe)
    self.but_go.grid(column=0, row=7)
    self.but_safe = Button(root, text="Сохранить", font=("Arial Bold", 14))
    self.but_safe.grid(column=1, row=6)
    self.but_del = Button(root, text="Удалить", font=("Arial Bold", 14))
    self.but_del.grid(column=1, row=7)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    run = Application(root)
    Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.master` in this code *is* the root window.  No additional `.root` is needed on that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, when you are changing the Root Title and geometry, you do not need to call the `root` simply leaving it as `self.master.geometry('400x300+200+200')` will work fine.

Secondly, when using `from tkinter import *` you do not need to use `tk.Frame` you can just use `Frame` as Python will recognise this as a class name.

Thirdly one of your button commands `self.safe` will cause an error because this method is not defined nor is it a built in Tk command.

Improved code...

```py
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.initialize_user_interface()

    def initialize_user_interface(self):
        self.master.title("Работа с планом")
        self.master.geometry('400x300+200+200')

        self.lbl_name = Label(root, text='Название проекта:', font=("Arial Bold", 14))
        self.lbl_name.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.txt_name = Entry(root, width=50, font=("Arial Bold", 14))
        self.txt_name.grid(column=1, row=1)

        self.lbl_lic = Label(root, text='Жидкость для работы:')
        self.lbl_lic.grid(column=0, row=2)
        self.txt_lic = Entry(root, width=50, font=("Arial Bold", 14))
        self.txt_lic.grid(column=1, row=2)

        self.lbl_tank = Label(root, text='Имя танкера для работы:')
        self.lbl_tank.grid(column=0, row=3)
        self.txt_tank = Entry(root, width=50, font=("Arial Bold", 14))
        self.txt_tank.grid(column=1, row=3)

        self.lbl_desk = Label(root, text='Описание действий сотрудника:')
        self.lbl_desk.grid(column=0, row=4)
        self.txt_desk = Entry(root, width=50, font=("Arial Bold", 14))
        self.txt_desk.grid(column=1, row=4)

        self.lbl_agr = Label(root, text='Согласование работ с нормоконтролером:')
        self.lbl_agr.grid(column=0, row=5)
        self.txt_agr = Entry(root, width=50, font=("Arial Bold", 14))
        self.txt_agr.grid(column=1, row=5)
        self.txt_name.focus()

        self.but_b = Button(root, text="Назад", font=("Arial Bold", 14))
        self.but_b.grid(column=0, row=6)
        self.but_go = Button(root, text="Вперед", font=("Arial Bold", 14), command=None)
        self.but_go.grid(column=0, row=7)
        self.but_safe = Button(root, text="Сохранить", font=("Arial Bold", 14))
        self.but_safe.grid(column=1, row=6)
        self.but_del = Button(root, text="Удалить", font=("Arial Bold", 14))
        self.but_del.grid(column=1, row=7)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    run = Application(root)
    Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```